# How to hide multiple html elements in single jquery function via parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML :

```
<div id="a1">12345</div>
<div id="a2">6789</div>
<h1 id="a3">asdffgg</h1>
<a href="#" id="a4" >go</a>
<p id="a5">jklo</p>
<h4 id="a6">just</h4>
<button id="btn" onclick="hide();">hide</button>
```

JS :

```
<script> function hide(){ ....? } </script>
```

Above are my code....

how to hide selected elements via parameter
such as **onclick="hide(a5,a6,a4);"**
please help me...
thank you..

Comment: Hello, please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and help us help you by providing a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have attempted thus far.

Comment: I observed the following function call pattern: when I loaded the jQuery documentation for hide() http://api.jquery.com/hide/

$( "#hideStuff" ).click(function() {
  $( "#a5", "#a6", "#a4" ).hide( );
});

// Its not a good practice to name function calls using the same names as other methods as there may be name collisions. Try this button:
<button id="btn" onclick="hideStuff();">hide</button>

Answer (score 2):

Send them as one string like `"a5,a6,a4"` then parse them into multi-id's selector using `split()/join()` like :

```
$('#' + selectors.split(',').join(',#')).hide();
```

Else use common class for all the elements you want to hide and use it as selector like :

```
$('.common_class').hide();
```

Code:

```js
function hide(selectors) {
  $('#' + selectors.split(',').join(',#')).hide(); //Selector will be '#a5,#a6,#a4'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn" onclick="hide('a5,a6,a4');">hide</button>
<div id="a1">12345</div>
<div id="a2">6789</div>
<h1 id="a3">asdffgg</h1>
<a href="#" id="a4">go</a>
<p id="a5">jklo</p>
<h4 id="a6">just</h4>
```

Comment: (y) for the logic and mentioning use of class. Using class is the best choice in this case @ZakariaAcharki

Answer (score 1):

You haven't even bothered looking for the answer... a simple Google search will reveal 100's of example.

The easiest will be to add a common class to all your elements and use that:

```
  <div id="a1" class=myclass>12345</div>
  <div id="a2" class=myclass>6789</div>
  <h1 id="a3" class=myclass>asdffgg</h1>
  <a href="#" id="a4"  class=myclass>go</a>
  <p id="a5" class=myclass>jklo</p>
  <h4 id="a6" class=myclass>just</h4>
  <button id="btn" onclick="hide();">hide</button>
  <script> function hide(){ $(".myclass").hide(); } </script>
```

Comment: But OP needs elements by certain ids hidden. Not classes.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use classes. 2) Hide parent children. 3) If none of these solution is possible and if the id are all formatted this way ("aX") you can try :

```
var completed = false;
var counter = 0;

while (completed === false) {
    counter++
    if ($('#a'+counter).length)) {
        $('#a'+counter).hide();
    }
    else {
        completed = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter all the elements with ids starting with `#a` and from there compare the ids passed in your function via `find()` and hide them all as so:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    hide('a5', 'a6', 'a4');
  });

  function hide(...ids) {
    $('[id^="a"]').filter(function(index, elem) {
      return ids.find(function(id) {
        return elem.id === id;
      });
    }).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a1">
  12345
</div>

<div id="a2">
  6789
</div>

<h1 id="a3">
  asdffgg
</h1>
<a href="#" id="a4">
  go
</a>

<p id="a5">
  jklo
</p>

<h4 id="a6">
  just
</h4>

<button id="btn">hide</button>
```